# How to avoid an infinite loop with useEffect in this case? (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

So I want to call `run()` whenever `a` (in the component's state) is changed.

`run()` sets the value of another state variable, b.

```
  import {computeWithB} from '../helpers/compute'

  const [a, setA] = useState()
  const [b, setB] = useState()

  const run = () => {
    result = computeWithB(b)
    setB(result)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    run();
  }, [a, run]);
```

If I remove `run` from the dependency array, the code works how I want it to, but I get the expected exhaustive-deps warning, and it's probably not the best solution.

Currently, an infinite loop results.

I cannot move run() into the useEffect callback, because I also need to be able to call run() from elsewhere in the component.

If I do

```
const run = useCallback(() => {
  result = computeWithB(b)
    setB(result)
}, [b]);
```

an infinite loop results from setting `b` while it is a dependency.

How do I call `run()` once every time `a` changes?

Would appreciate any advice!

Comment: why you need to add run as dependency for `useEffect`??

Comment: I get a warning otherwise, and multiple sources / the official docs say that you shouldn't 'lie' about useEffect dependencies. There should be a better way to do it.

Comment: u can disable the linter error instead of adding extra code which is `useCallback` here check this post https://reacttraining.com/blog/when-to-use-functions-in-hooks-dependency-array/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The run function within useEffect set the state which triggers a re-render. Now since a re-render causes a new reference of run function to be created and run is used as a dependency to useEffect, the useEffect is called again, causing an infinite loop

You can make use of useCallback for run function to avoid a new reference on each render and make use of functional state update within it like

```
 import {computeWithB} from '../helpers/compute'

  const [a, setA] = useState()
  const [b, setB] = useState()

  const run = useCallback(() => {
    setB(prevB => computeWithB(prevB))
  }, [setB])

  useEffect(() => {
    run();
  }, [a, run]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked well! The functional state update was the key.